# Random file showing up in various directories. How to trace its creator?

Tags: linux, files

I am finding a 0 byte file named `^-` (that is a caret and a dash) in various directories on my file system. I use zsh with oh-my-zsh and I am pretty sure something in there is creating it but I really have no idea.

Is there a way to tell who created a file?

Comment: Did you check the owner and timestamp of the files?

Comment: Always owned by me. The current one is date Feb 10 which is almost a month ago.

Comment: Do you have a monthly crontab job? Some script that might want to replace something at the beginning of the line? The files in the various directories, do they all have the same timestamp?

Comment: @CollinPeters: Did you check creation time? It's not the same what `ls` shows, it may be but it doesn't have to.